# Microsoft SGEN Tool Changes Tool Version In Comment Only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, auto-generate, xsd.exe, sgen

I came across some strange behavior with the SGEN tool that is used to generate classes from SGEN's.

In the class files that are generated by the tool, there is a comment at the top of the file it says that the file was generated using `version 2.0.50727.xxxx`. Looking at the previous history of the file, this `xxxx` number changes every time someone different rebuilds the file.  Although this comment changes the attributes in the source that specify the version of the tool, the actual tool used (`2.0.50727.42`) remain consistent.  This number has never matched to the number in the comment.

Until today, there was a 1:1 correlation between the builder and that number.  However, today, the builder had it insert a number different from what he received in the past.  He is using the same machine though and setup as before. I can't determine why this number would change and what would be causing this behavior.

Has anyone else observed similar behavior with SGEN or know what is causing it?

Is it bug with the code that generates that comment or is there a potential for a problem here?

Comment: XSD does not change that number. If it's changing, then something else is changing it.

Comment: Ahh, yes you are correct I believe it is the SGEN tool.  I was mistaken about what tool was doing the generation.

Comment: Is that the SGEN version or the .NET version? Any service packs or security fixes applied for either .NET or the source of SGEN that you're using (VS2008? Windows SDK?) ?